# Should an alternative to silicone sealant be used if I'm new at it?

Tags: windows, caulking

I had to research various types of caulk for windows, and the answer was that I should use silicone (or mastic?). Why is silicone is always preferred when you can remove, can't caulk over it and can't paint over it? Compared to something like Lexel synthetic rubber where you can just redo it without removing old caulk and is more easy for non professionals.

Comment: Are you caulking inside the building, or outside the building?

Comment: VTC as opinion-based, but here's mine: Silicone is more flexible than latex-based caulks, and therefore more durable. That said, it's inferior in bond and durability to modern paintable caulks like urethane.

Comment: So if someone who has no experience would the advice be silicone? Because where I'm from people dread using it because it creates a mess, so they don't have experience.